# How to find difference in 2 rows subject to multiple consitions in dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
NO. Month  Year  Km   Diff
1    1     2010  200   200
1    1     2010  200   200
1    1     2010  200   200
1    2     2010  400   200
1    2     2010  400   200 
1    2     2010  400   200
1    3     2010  800   400
1    4     2010  1500  700
```

So, I want to take difference subject to `Month` and `Year` conditions having same serial No. column using `dplyr` R package. So, How to give multiple conditions subject to Serial No. and make cumulative difference?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're looking for? What is the expected output? Also, can you refer to the columns as you have written them in your data table? E.g. by "Serial No." are you referring to `NO.`?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for a good reproducible example criteria in `R`. `dput`ing your data would be a good start.

Comment: Not sure I understand the end goal. Are you wanting to add up the `Km` and `Diff` columns, aggregated by `NO.`, `Month` and `Year` and then compute the difference? If so, you'd do this. `library(dplyr) ; df2 <- df %>% group_by(`NO.`, Month, Year) %>% summarise(tot_km = sum(Km), tot_diff = sum(Diff)) %>% mutate(agg_diff = tot_km - tot_diff)`.

Comment: In this I want the expected output shown in column Diff as it is difference in km for the vehicle no. 1 subject to month and year constraint. If specific vehicle is not running then I will take same km reading as existing in the current month.

Comment: df <- data.frame(No.= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                 Month=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',6)), 
                 Year = c(rep('a',4),rep('b',2),rep('c',4)),
                 Km=c(200,200,200,500,400,1200,800,1200,1200,1600),
                 Diff = c(200,200,200,300,400,800,800,1200,1200,400))
Here is dataframe. The expected output should be Diff column in dataframe which is subject to No,month and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the first example wasn't complete enough to handle all the cases. Finally, if I have understood correctly, here is an answer with `dplyr` and `na.locf` from `zoo` package.

We create an additional column `Value_Change` which would have only the first value of the group and the value when it changes, rest all would be `NA` and then we fill those `NA`'s with latest non-NA values using `na.locf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
   group_by(No.) %>%
    mutate(Value_Change = c(Km[1], ifelse(diff(Km) == 0, NA, diff(Km))), 
           New_diff = na.locf(Value_Change))


#      No.  Month   Year    Km  Diff Value_Change New_diff
#     (dbl) (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)         (dbl)    (dbl)
#1      1      A      a   200   200           200      200
#2      1      A      a   200   200            NA      200
#3      1      A      a   200   200            NA      200
#4      1      A      a   200   200            NA      200
#5      1      B      b   500   300           300      300
#6      1      B      b   500   300            NA      300
#7      1      B      c  1000   500           500      500
#8      2      B      c  1200  1200          1200     1200
#9      2      B      d  1200  1200            NA     1200
#10     2      B      d  1600   400           400      400
```

Comment: df <- data.frame(No.= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), Month=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',6)), 
                 Year = c(rep('a',4),rep('b',2),rep('c',2),rep('d',2)), 
                 Km=c(200,200,200,200,500,500,1000,1200,1200,1600),
                 Diff = c(200,200,200,200,300,300,500,1200,1200,400)
                 ) If target variable is No. subject to Month and year. Expected Output like column Diff for km column

Comment: @Mahesh The logic isn't clear to me. Also, if this is a new question then I would suggest you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: The question is same- If for a No. 1 vehicle with month and year considered, if vehicle is not running for (month +year) combination then it is same km reading else if anyone (month +year) combination changes then it should be difference between current(month +year) combination with previous (month +year) combination. Same for No. 2 vehicle. The dataframe is correct as mentioned above.

Comment: @Mahesh Hi, I have updated the answer. Please have a look if this is what you want.